# How to add fields in array list in mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, robo3t

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "teams" : 
    [ 
        {
            "type" : "local",
            "isEnabled" : "true",
            "names" : 
            [ 
                { "name": "kumar","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Goa","Age":"U25" },
                { "name": "kannan","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Kerala","Age":"U25"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type" : "national",
            "isEnabled" : "true",
            "names" : 
            [ 
                { "name": "kumar","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Goa","Age":"U25" },
                { "name": "kannan","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Kerala","Age":"U25"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type" : "international",
            "isEnabled" : "true",
            "names" : 
            [ 
                { "name": "kumar","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Goa","Age":"U25" },
                { "name": "kannan","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Kerala","Age":"U25"}
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I have multiple docs in the same format in a mongodb collection. I wanted to append the below lines into **names** array also only for "type: local" in each docs of the collections. I tried $push and its appending in all teams array as i am finding difficulty to add this condition **only for "type":"local"**

{
"name":"jack","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":" "Karnataka","Age":"U25"
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [positional operator : $[]](http://$%5B%3Cidentifier%3E%5D%C2%B6)

```
db.collection.update({
  "teams.type": "local"
},
{
  $push: {
    "teams.$[element].names": {
      "name": "jack",
      "Nationality": "indian",
      "BirthPlace": "Karnataka",
      "Age": "U25"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element.type": "local"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xh90x-Cqunh)

Comment: Thanks a lot AlexisG. It saves my day.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the answer as accepted to "close" the question